# FsReadOnlyArchiveFilesystemException

Tags: java, file, truezip

Hi I am trying to unzip files using TrueZIP and while doing so I get an exception

> `de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystemException: This is a read-only archive file system!`

It works for some files and throws exception for others.

So I tried changing the permission and making it writable but that doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
public void unzipFiles(TFile[] files){
    try{
        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Processing please wait ...");
            if(files[i].isArchive()){
                if(files[i].getName().endsWith(".zip")){
                    System.out.println(files[i].getName());
                    System.out.println("Is writable "+files[i].canWrite());
                    //change the file permission to be writable
                    if(files[i].canWrite() == false){
                        files[i].setWritable(true);
                        files[i].setExecutable(true);
                        System.out.println("After setting it writeable "+files[i].canWrite());
                    }
                    String filename = files[i].getName();
                    String pathToExtract = files[i].getParent() + "\\" + filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
                    File createdirectory = new File(pathToExtract);

                    TFile directoryToExtract = new TFile(pathToExtract);
                    TFile.cp_rp(files[i], directoryToExtract, TArchiveDetector.NULL, TArchiveDetector.NULL);
                    System.out.println("Unzipping files ..");
                    TFile.rm_r(files[i]);
                    System.out.println("Deleting Zip file..");
                    numOfZips = numOfZips + 1;
                    unzipFiles(directoryToExtract.listFiles());
                }
            }else{
                if(files[i].isDirectory()){
                    unzipFiles(files[i].listFiles());
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that TrueZIP does not support permissions. So `setWritable` and `setExecutable` are about the only methods which do not get overridden to have a meaning in an archive file. If you had checked their boolean return value, you would have recognized that they return `false` if the file object is addressing an entry within an archive file.

Apart from this, I don't see where you would modify an archive file and so I can't comment how you get an `FsReadOnlyArchiveFileSystemException`. It's generally thrown if you try to modify a read-only archive file system, i.e. if the archive file is read-only.

If you provide a stack trace, then it may become obvious why this happened.